# Fix a vintage computer (IBM PS/2 55SX) without a DS1287 Real Time Clock

Tags: integrated-circuit, rtc

I want to reanimate an a old vintage computer, the IBM PS/2 55SX.

The dead component is the DS1287 Real Time Clock (in particular, the battery inside).

Is it possible to simulate with a BASIC Stamp micro-controller the behavior
of a DS1287 so that I can boot my old IBM PS/2 55SX?

The DS1287 pin are damaged (I mean current can not flow between the broken DS1287 and its socket) so I can't modify it, to use another battery.
[image]

Comment: That looks highly fixable. Look at the mods that people do to add an external battery. Then consider soldering wires as required to a new IC socket that will plug into the existing socket. (Machine screw" sockets work well for this. || OR use the new DS12877 from Digikey - see below.

Answer (score 6):

- A direct replacement appears to be available ex stock from Digikey in the form of a DS12877 - see below.

---

Digikey have the DS12885 and Ds12887 ICs in stock. [See here](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/cat/integrated-circuits-ics/clock-timing-real-time-clocks/2556170?k=ds128)
These are stated by Dallas to be direct replacements for the old IC
.
It's a bit hard to believe but the datasheet claims that the 12887 24 pin DIP is functionally identical to your module and has the battery included and sells ex stock for $10 - rush out and buy one now :-).
[Price and availability here](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/DS12887%2B/DS12887%2B-ND/956874)

If this is in fact a cruel illusion and this is the IC and not a complete module then they have the 12887 and 12885 and you could build a new module with relative ease - see 1st article below and others.

[Datasheet DS12885 / DS12887](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/DS12885-DS12C887A.pdf)

---

Here is an excellent page on [modifiying a DS1287](http://www.mcamafia.de/mcapage0/dsrework.htm)

Yee Ha !!!

[image]

Note that he says:

- Basically the DS1287 is a DS1285 chip, where the pins for the xtal-connection and the battery are bended upwards. Then the battery and xtal are placed atop of the chip, connected to the pins and everything is covered with a pretty rigid protective compound.

  The DS1387 is the same chip with an additional integrated 4K SRAM. All described modifictions apply to this chip as well.

If your bottom pins are damaged it may **still** be possible to hack into the unit.

Another modification page [here](http://classic-computers.org.nz/blog/2009-10-10-renovating-a-dallas-battery-chip.htm)

If you think your module is damaged beyond repair [THIS](http://www.instructables.com/id/Revive-a-pre-historic-dinosaur-an-IBM-PS2-55SX-/) PS2 55SX incredible repair record may convince you that it is not. I'm amazed that he didn't destroy it in the process. he gives advice on how YOU can do it more subtly.

[image]
http://www.instructables.com/image/FO4JO46FKLD2FOO/Into-the-belly-of-the-beast.jpg

---

[Yet another version](http://www.walshcomptech.com/ps2/dallasrework.html)

[VBG !!!!!!!!  :-)](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=DS1287&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=XNweT8b_HsfLmAXapYWZDg&ved=0CHQQsAQ&biw=1333&bih=750)  So many ! So many!!!!

Comment: Soldering directly to a coin cell is a bad idea.  And alkaline batteries for a shelf-life-limited application are another bad idea.  Coin cell holders are $1 in ones from DigiKey.

Comment: @markrages - Alkalines are getting surprisingly good - out to about 7 years now if you believe the manufacturer's data - and if the cells are external then changing them is not an issue. | Coin cell soldering - Yes. If you look at what came before the coin cell soldering on that rebuild - I think he could have welded it and expected it to have lived :-).